# Check Palindrome using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, palindrome

I am trying to implement a function that will check to see if a word is a palindrome Below is the code that i have tried to use. the code works for one letter words obviously and words that don't start and end with the same letter. It fails on anything else. Please help

```
bool is_palindrome(int start, int end, const string & str)
{
    if (str[start] != str[end])
        return false;
    else if (start == end)
        return true;
    else
        return is_palindrome(start++, end--, str);

    return false;
}
```

here is the main function that tis function calls
http://csel.cs.colorado.edu/%7Eekwhite/CSCI2270Fall2011/recursion_lab/palindrome.cxx

Comment: What happens if your string has even length?

Comment: The ++ and -- operators are not doing what you think they're doing.

Comment: "Fails"? Did you step through and find out _where_ it failed? On paper? With a pen?

Comment: I'm starting with odd length it doesn't even work for odd

Comment: Please do not undo formatting fixes. Better still, don't make the formatting errors and typos in the first place!

Comment: @Sean: There's more than one problem here. Consider each piece of advice given.

Comment: You say "It fails": are you running into an infinite loop, by chance?

Comment: Also, please tag as homework.  It helps others determine how to answer your question appropriately.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that in a language without tail recursion optimisation, recursion isn't the best way to check for a palindrome. Do this to learn recursion, but don't consider it a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`start++` increments the [local] variable `start`, and evaluates to the *old* value. You want to evaluate to the new value, and you don't need to alter the local variable at all.

So write `start+1, end-1` instead, and then consider the case where your string has an even number of characters because there is another issue there.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

Don't you need to use the prefix increment/decrement operators?

```
return is_palindrome(++start,--end, str);
```

Also, you need to make the test start >= end for it to work on an even number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
bool is_palindrome(int start, int end, const string& str)
{
        if (str[start] != str[end])
          return false;
        else if ((start == end) || (start < end))
          return true;
        else
          return is_palindrome(++start, --end, str);

        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure isit 100% working but for me it works:

```
bool is_palindrome(int start, int end, const string& str)
{
    if (str[start] != str[end])
      return false;
    else if (str[start] == str[end])
      {
        if (start <= end)
        return is_palindrome(start+1, end-1, str);
        return true;
      }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

recursively calls is palindrome function to check the string is palindrome or not.
**bool is_palindrome(int start, int end, const string& str)**
the start and end variables is used to contol the matching process for the palindrome.
after each matching the next iteration is given using the recursion format